# force windows server 2008 to use a certain IP address for outbound connections

Tags: windows-server-2008, ip

My windows server 2008 has multiple IP4 addresses, how do I force outbound traffic to only use one of them?

We have multiple applications (ASP.Net) that send email via external SMTP servers which have to be locked down by IP. We also on occasion have to connect to an FTP server that is also locked down by IP.

My first thought was to relay emails through the local SMTP server but there are multiple client SMTP server that we have to connect to, so I was looking for a solution that would encompass all outbound traffic on the server.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look [here](http://www.softlion.com/blogs/post/2009/09/03/What-outbound-ip-is-used-by-windows-and-when-.aspx)

You may also try to set the binding order on the NIC's advanced setting.

Comment: your link appears to be dead